# D3 event: Type definitions in version 6+

Tags: typescript, d3.js, events, types

I have a group of widgets developed with d3 (version 5) and now I have to migrate them to version 7. In the migration guide https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide I've learned the new syntax for events:

```
// before
element.on('click', (d, i, e) => ...


// now
element.on('click', (event, d) => ...
```

Once I switched to the new syntax the program started running again. Yay!

The issue now is that I use typescript in this project! And Though I have installed the latest @types/...

```
  "dependencies": {
      "d3": "^7.1.1",
         ...

  "devDependencies": {
      "@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
         ...
```

...I keep having trouble with type definitions and Intellisense when it comes to events.

```
// 1. before (Worked fine)
element.on('click', (d: MyData, i: number, e: whatever[]) => ...


// 2. introducing types == Error back! ❌  
element.on('click', (event: PointerEvent, d: MyData) => ...


// 3. then, my (ugly) workaround:
element.on('click', (event: any , d: any) => ...
```

What's funny is that though I have @types/d3 v7.0.1 installed, the Typings system looks like it still holds reference to the old v5 format. **Somehow Intellisense still thinks my first param is data and the second is a numeric index**:

[image]

[image]

...But in real life what I get is { event: PointerEvent, d: MyData }, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

So, in a nutshell, feels like there's a problem with D3's types declaration as Intellisense thinks the Event's still under the v5 format while in real life it's not.

Do anyone know how to fix this typing thing?
It's really annoying having to assign "any" to the whole thing inside my events.

Comment: Having the same exact issue in WebStorm, had to add `any` to event and data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding a utility type of `D3Event` to my codebase that accepts 2 type args:

```js
export type D3Event<T extends Event, E extends Element> = T & { currentTarget: E }
```

Then I can use it like this:

```js
selection.on('mouseover', (event: D3Event<MouseEvent, SVGGElement>, d: SomeType) => { ... }
```

It's a little more verbose but it's much stricter than `any`

Answer (score 3):

As you are well aware, it is usually best practice to avoid `any` like the Plague, which is the reason why you are trying to narrow it down to a particular type! In case of the event listener's type definition you are out of luck, though. Looking at the the [`.on`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on) method's [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L841) you will notice that the `event` parameter is indeed typed as `any` allowing for the most generic event handling:

```
on(typenames: string, listener: (this: GElement, event: any, d: Datum) => void, options?: any): this;
```

For that reason, your second approach is going to fail leaving you with the third approach as the correct solution.

Comment: I checked the definition link, still the way VSCode's dealing with my event handler's args is kinda odd... Looking at the pictures I just added in the question you can see that intellisense still thinks there's a number as 2nd arg.  As 1st arg I get my data! (thought it's named "event ") . No event "any" as shown it appears in the declarations...

Comment: Intellisense is clearly handling that "on" function as if it was v5...

Comment: @FelipeChernicharo Your assumption regarding the type definitions' version being v5 is not correct. The first parameter clearly is defined as type `event` which is an indicator for v6+ typings. Using the type definitions IntelliSense identifies the second parameter to be of the type of the data bound to the selection, though, which, because it is `number`, might be confused with the former index parameter. My guess is that the data bound to your selection is an array of `number`s, correct?

Comment: @altocumumlus. I just added another picture showing the format of my ```event``` and ```data```. No, it's not an array of numbers that I'm binding to, it's rather an array of ```objects```. Looking at the pictures you can see how Intellisense still thinks v5 style  while in the console  the real format 's displayed  ```{ Event, Data }```  at v7 style.